# 'Hello World' in Assembly in Eclipse CDT, using Oracle VirtualBox: Build Failed

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64, linker-errors, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to write a 64-bit assembly language program in GNU assembler using AT&T syntax that prints `Hello World`. I am linking with GCC.

**Using Debian 10, x86_64 Architecture, Eclipse CDT 2020-09, on Oracle VirtualBox**

Note: *Building was successful in NASM, using Command line*

Posted on elclipse.org/Forums under CDT also. But NO solution

**Steps Followed:**

File > New > Project > C Project > Empty Project, Linux GCC

Project Name: HelloASM > Next > Debug, Release > Finish

File > New > Source File > Source File: hello.S > Finish

hello.S:

```
.section .data
message: .string "Hello World!\n"

.section .text

# this directive allows the linker to see the "main" label
# which is our entry point
.globl main

# this directive allows the eclipse gdb to see a function called "main"
.func main
main:
mov $4, %eax
mov $1, %ebx
mov $message, %ecx
mov $14, %edx
int $0x80
mov $0, %eax
```

Project > Build Project

***Error..***

```
09:46:57 **** Build of configuration Debug for project HelloASM ****
make all 
Building file: ../hello.S
Invoking: GCC Assembler
as  -o "hello.o" "../hello.S"
Finished building: ../hello.S
 
Building target: HelloASM
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc  -o "HelloASM"  ./hello.o   
/usr/bin/ld: ./hello.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:31: HelloASM] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

09:46:58 Build Failed. 3 errors, 0 warnings. (took 666ms)
```

Why am I getting this linker error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you intending to make a 32-bit program or a 64-bit one? What you show is that you are generating 64-bit code with 32-bit instructions. The address in the `.data` section can't be represented in a 32-bit register. You could fix the immediate problem by linking with `-static` option. Note: your `main` function doesn't do a `ret` or an exit system call

Comment: @Michael Petch: I am new to it. I want 64 bit program. Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: @ Michael Petch: Also, **how to remove the [Duplicate] tag on the question?**. Because, it is in Eclipse CDT, NOT on Command line.

Comment: I didn't mark it as a duplicate (Another user named @Michael did). It is probably a duplicate of another question but I haven't looked. I disagree that this is a duplicate of the  one specified. To answer the question in your comment though you have to use the 64-bit system calls which can be found here: https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/ . An example that should work and uses RIP relative addressing can be found here: https://pastebin.com/raw/kthEDVtR

Comment: The fact you are using CDT isn't really relevant since the real problem is the code itself and not the IDE.

Comment: @Michael Petch: **Sir, Thank You very much!** It solved. Been struggling for 3 days. Posted  with so much details in Eclipse.og/foums under CDT, Stack overflow, and in Reddit (today). You are absolutely precise and to the point. **Hats off to you!**. Now, two requests: (1) Can you please answer it formally? (2) How to remove that [duplicate] tag. I want this solution to be useful to others also.

Comment: @Michael Petch: One more request: (3)  Can you please show code snippet to create a Makefile also?